# Use CSSearchQuery in QLPreviewingController?

Tags: ios, quicklook, corespotlight

When implementing a `QLPreviewingController`, we only get the Spotlight `uniqueIdentifier` but not the actual `CSSearchableItem`.
I thought I could use `CSSearchQuery` with a query like this

> uniqueIdentifier == "\(identifier)"

to fetch the `CSSearchableItem` of the selected item from Spotlight. However, I always receive an error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application."

Is it not possible to call Spotlight from a QuickLook Preview extension? Is there another way to retrieve the `CSSearchableItem` for the item to be previewed?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a possibly related problem, that I can't access a cloud service from my QL extension. I suspect it has to do with sandboxing, which seems to be a configurable target capability on MacOS. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55493267/4543629

Comment: No, I've abandoned the idea of creating a QLPreviewingController because I couldn't solve this. I assume it's not possible.